# Unable to setup Entity Framework to Oracle. Data Source Name dropdown is empty, and trying EZConnect gives exception

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

I am trying to connect a test application via EF to an Oracle database.

I have Visual Studio 2013, and I've just installed the latest Oracle ODAC (ODAC 12c Release 2 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.1.0.1.2)).  I do the following

1. Created a test application
2. Add Entity Framework 6 from nuget (I also tried EF5)
3. select to add a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model
4. select EF Designer from database
5. click New Connection

It is at this point that the "Data Source Name" dropdown is empty:

[image: empty data source name dropdown]

It says that it's looking for the tnsnames.ora file located in the path:

c:\oracle12\product\12.1.0\client_2\network\admin\tnsnames.ora

And I DO have a tnsnames.ora file there with 3 aliases defined.  If I pick "Search" and select that same file, those 3 names show up under "Aliases"

[image]

Some suggested changing the Connection Type to EZ Connect and manually putting in the connection info.  When I do that and try to continue or select Test Connection I get "The type initializer for 'OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution' threw an exception."

[image]

I'm at a loss at this point :(

Comment: I usually dislike these kind of "answers" but can you please reinstall ODTwithODAC? That last error with EZ connect seems very unusual, as though there may be an installation problem. Also, verify that the TNS_ADMIN entry in the 32 bit machine.config points to the tnsnames.ora that the dialog is telling you it is using.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am having the same issue.

Comment: @JDS unfortunately not.  I kinda gave up and went in a different direction.

Comment: Did you do away with Oracle all together or did you find a workaround?

Comment: We gave up on using EF with Oracle and just reverted to using standard ADO.Net with business objects.

Answer (score 0):

use the unmanaged version of the driver. that solved my problem